# git - How to get files changed with specific commitid without update to head?

Tags: bash, git

I want to make a automated test system. Users upload or change their script, when they push file to git, system will get the commit action, and know the commit id, like `3c6a88d527ccaefabf98d00f47f04789f01e2830`, and boot a docker to run changed script.

at first, git clone all file to a directory, after that get what files is changed by order:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <id>
```

After a long time, there will be a lot of scripts in the repository, I don't want to pull all the scripts to the local directory every time I test.Is there any command to pull only part of the files I want?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Shows commit logs and diff output
git whatchanged <sha-1>
```

[image]

#### Using diff-tree (as you figured out)

```
# Fetch out changes (no need to checkout branches) 
git fetch --all --prune

# Now print out the changes
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <id>
```